# How can I edit a project locally and push the changes to my vps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, debian, cloud

I have a project and I can test it only on my vps and not on my local machine, how can I push changes to it instead of pushing to github and then pulling the changes in the vps? I know I can use vim but I prefer coding on vscode

I'm using digitalocean btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SFTP` or `FTP` protocols. Using VSCode, you can also try to install [this SFTP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp).

You'll then **edit directly your code on your remote server**, using automatic SFTP push and pull.

Here is more informations (from DO) about SFTP transfer : [How To Use SFTP to Securely Transfer Files with a Remote Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!